# Program freezes or stalls when clicking on a popup menu. (function)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I am having a issue where when I run a certain procedure on a particular form, the program freezes.

I Have ran this many times in other areas of the program without issue.

I have found that If I put a breakpoint or a ShowMessage before or on the procedure It runs smoothly.

Also while its frozen if I go out of the window(software) at all and come back in then it works?!(like if I just click the windows start button)...  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using threads? Where does it freeze exactly? (Pause the application when it doesn't respond anymore and have a look at the call stack).

Comment: What are you doing to implement the pause?

Comment: cure the disease rather than the symptoms

Comment: Try `Application.ProcessMessages;` instead of pause, if that helps then you have a problem that some message you're relaying on haven't been processed yet.

Comment: I have tried the application.ProcessMessages but It does not work.
Thanks.

Comment: Where does the debugger tell you that you are waiting. Not sure how good Delphi debugger will be here.

Comment: Yeah, It didn't make sense to me at all and I didin't know how to describe the problem or debug it...   But I did find a solution that took care of the root of the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it.  Along with some more information needed to explain the solution that I didn't previously realize had relevance to the question.

The function that was being called was accessed through a popup menu.

The popup menu came form the main form and for some reason was popping up when I right clicked on a PageControl(not part of the main form) even when I didin't have the property set.

Solution - Added the Main form popup menu to the PageControl PopupMenu property.

No freeze!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't sound like the correct approach to fixing your issue, but you can use Delphi's TTimer class to wait a specified amount of time before continuing with whatever process is hanging.

I suspect there is a logical problem with the existing code though, and any timing fix is only going to resolve the issue in your particular environment.

Comment: I use this function in a lot of different places in my program.  This freezing issue only occurs when called in this particular area(form) of the program.  If I put a simple breakpoint then it goes off normal without a hitch.  I will try the TTimer approach thanks.

Comment: A timer is not the way to wait. A timer is the way to get poked at periodic intervals and respond to those pokes. If you want to wait then use `Sleep`. However, as I have said many times here, if `Sleep` is the solution then you probably don't understand the problem.